# Question about Lagrange interpolation polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $x_0, x_1, \dots x_n$ be $n+1$ distinct points in $\mathbb{R}$, $a_0, a_1, \dots a_n$ are any numbers, and $b_0, b_1, \dots b_n$ be some further set of numbers. Find a number $k$ such that there exists a unique polynomial of degree $k$ with 
$p(x_i)=a_i$ and $p'(x_i)=b_i$ for all $i=0, \dots n$.

The solution said the lowest value for $k$ always has a solution is $2n+2.$

I don't understand why the lowest $k$ is not $2n+1,$ since the dimension of a degree $2n+1$ polynomial is $2n+2,$ so such polynomials span $\mathbb{R}^{2n+2}$, and I cannot figure out what a matrix representing such a linear transformation would look like. Since $p$ is in dimension $2n+2,$ and $p'$ in $2n+1,$ seems $p$ and $p'$ cannot fit into a single matrix. Any help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to form a system of equations of the form 
$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & x_0 & x_0^2 & \cdots & x_0^k \\
0 & 1 & 2x_0 & \cdots &k x_0^{k-1} \\
1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & \cdots & x_1^k \\
0 & 1 & 2x_1 & \cdots &k x_1^{k-1} \\
&&&\vdots
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} p_0 \\ p_1 \\ \vdots\\ p_k \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a_0 \\ b_0 \\ \vdots\\ a_n \\b_n \end{bmatrix}$.

This is a map $:\mathbb{R}^{k+1} \to \mathbb{R}^{2n+2}$, so you need $k+1 \ge 2n+2$ or equivalently $k \ge 2n+1$ at a minimum.

Comment: Sorry, the solution said smallest k is 2n+2, I've typed it wrong.

Comment: Well, take $n=1$ then a polynomial of degree $k=1$ will work for any $a_0,b_0$.